# How to get phone number from contact in Nativescript Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, nativescript

When I run this code;

```
let desiredFields = ['display_name','phone','thumbnail','email','organization'];

console.log('Loading contacts...');
let timer = new Date().getTime();

Contacts.getContactsWorker(desiredFields).then((result) => {
  console.log(`Loading contacts completed in ${(new Date().getTime() - timer)} ms.`);
  console.log(`Found ${result.length} contacts.`);
  console.dir(result);
}, (e) => { console.dir(e); });
```

I get the following code as return;

```
JS: Loading contacts completed in 2704 ms.
JS: Found 2 contacts.
JS: ==== object dump start ====
JS: 0: {
JS:   "contact_id": 2,
JS:   "display_name": "example example ",
JS:   "phone": [
JS:     {
JS:       "account_name": "example@gmail.com",
JS:       "type": "mobile",
JS:       "number": "05364125322"
JS:     }
JS:   ]
JS: }
JS: 1: {
JS:   "contact_id": 1,
JS:   "display_name": "enes ozturk",
JS:   "phone": [
JS:     {
JS:       "account_name": "example@gmail.com",
JS:       "type": "mobile",
JS:       "number": "05364618553"
JS:     }
JS:   ]
JS: }
JS: ==== object dump end ====
```

**HOW TO GET NUMBER in THIS CODE ?**

https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-contacts-lite

Answer (score 0):

i found now
i am answering to my question  :)

```
  alert(result[0].phone[0].number);
```